# Efficiently increasing and decreasing elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two `numpy` arrays, I would like to uniformly increase and decrease each element in the input array and keep track of its impact on the output array. I will present a small example to make my question clearer.

Suppose I have the following array as my input array and would like to increase and decrease each value in each row two times (in real this will be thousands) with the increment of one (i.e., i) add 1s and then subtract 1s, ii) add 2s and subtract 2s etc).

```
Input = [[6 1 4 4 8 4 6 3 5 8]
 [7 9 9 2 7 8 8 9 2 6]
 [9 5 4 1 4 6 1 3 4 9]
 [2 4 4 4 8 1 2 1 5 8]]
```

In other words, I would like to obtain:

```
[[ 7  2  5  5  9  5  7  4  6  9]
 [ 5  0  3  3  7  3  5  2  4  7]
 [ 8  3  6  6 10  6  8  5  7 10]
 [ 4 -1  2  2  6  2  4  1  3  6]
 [ 8 10 10  3  8  9  9 10  3  7]
 [ 6  8  8  1  6  7  7  8  1  5]
 [ 9 11 11  4  9 10 10 11  4  8]
 [ 5  7  7  0  5  6  6  7  0  4]
 [10  6  5  2  5  7  2  4  5 10]
 [ 8  4  3  0  3  5  0  2  3  8]
 [11  7  6  3  6  8  3  5  6 11]
 [ 7  3  2 -1  2  4 -1  1  2  7]
 [ 3  5  5  5  9  2  3  2  6  9]
 [ 1  3  3  3  7  0  1  0  4  7]
 [ 4  6  6  6 10  3  4  3  7 10]
 [ 0  2  2  2  6 -1  0 -1  3  6]]
```

The second array keeps the output information for each row in the input array.

```
Output = 
[[3]
 [2]
 [7]
 [2]]
```

I have a parameter called `impactFactor` which tells me how many of the elements will impact the second array. Suppose `impactFactor = 3`, then the output will increase by three if the increment is all ones. The output will increase by six if the increment is two. The same logic applies to the subtract case. The expected results for the example provided is:

```
array([[ 6],
       [ 0],
       [ 9],
       [-3],
       [ 5],
       [-1],
       [ 8],
       [-4],
       [10],
       [ 4],
       [13],
       [ 1],
       [ 5],
       [-1],
       [ 8],
       [-4]])
```

As a result, I would like to store an updated input and output array. The code that I wrote is as follows and my question is whether it is possible to improve the performance of my code. I appreciate any help.

```
import numpy as np
import random


#you can change the number of rows and columns 
x = np.random.randint(1,100,(4,10))
y = np.random.randint(50,10,(4,1))


rep = 5 #how many different instances will be created
row, col = x.shape

impactFactor = 3


new_x = np.repeat(x, 2*rep, axis=0) #copy the original values fot both increase and decrease cases
arr = np.array([np.full((1, col), j*(i+1)) for i in range(rep) for j in[1,-1]]) # determine increase and decrease values
change =  np.repeat(arr[None,:] ,row ,axis=0).reshape(-1, col) # changes will repeat for each point in X



increase_in_y = np.repeat(np.array([[impactFactor*(i+1)*j] for i in range(rep) for j in [1,-1]])[None,:], row , axis=0).reshape(-1, 1) #compute how much each y will increase
repeat_y = np.repeat(y,2*rep,axis=0).reshape(-1, 1) #copy the original y values 
new_y= np.add(increase_in_y,repeat_y) #updated y values are here
new_x = np.add(new_x,change) # updated x values are here
```

Comment: Does this work? `new_y * new_x`

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what's going on.  I think I can see how you get from the input array to the large array, but what's the point of the second array?

Comment: @defladamouse you can think about this as a problem where the input array is your parameters and the output array is the results. Based on the changes in the input array, your results change in the output array.

Comment: yes, but what decides the value in the 2nd output array?

Comment: The output is impacted by the change factor * ````impactFactor````. For instance, if ````impactFactor```` is 5 and I decrease everything by four, then the output decreases by 20.

Answer (score -1):

Just use broadcasting:

```
Input = np.array([[6, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 6, 3, 5, 8,],
                  [7, 9, 9, 2, 7, 8, 8, 9, 2, 6,],
                  [9, 5, 4, 1, 4, 6, 1, 3, 4, 9,],
                  [2, 4, 4, 4, 8, 1, 2, 1, 5, 8,]]) 
rows, cols = Input.shape
factors = np.array([1,-1,2,-2])

out = (Input+factors[:,None,None]).swapaxes(1,0).reshape(len(factors)*rows, cols)
```

output:

```
array([[ 7,  2,  5,  5,  9,  5,  7,  4,  6,  9],
       [ 5,  0,  3,  3,  7,  3,  5,  2,  4,  7],
       [ 8,  3,  6,  6, 10,  6,  8,  5,  7, 10],
       [ 4, -1,  2,  2,  6,  2,  4,  1,  3,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 10,  3,  8,  9,  9, 10,  3,  7],
       [ 6,  8,  8,  1,  6,  7,  7,  8,  1,  5],
       [ 9, 11, 11,  4,  9, 10, 10, 11,  4,  8],
       [ 5,  7,  7,  0,  5,  6,  6,  7,  0,  4],
       [10,  6,  5,  2,  5,  7,  2,  4,  5, 10],
       [ 8,  4,  3,  0,  3,  5,  0,  2,  3,  8],
       [11,  7,  6,  3,  6,  8,  3,  5,  6, 11],
       [ 7,  3,  2, -1,  2,  4, -1,  1,  2,  7],
       [ 3,  5,  5,  5,  9,  2,  3,  2,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  3,  3,  3,  7,  0,  1,  0,  4,  7],
       [ 4,  6,  6,  6, 10,  3,  4,  3,  7, 10],
       [ 0,  2,  2,  2,  6, -1,  0, -1,  3,  6]])
```

Comment: What about the output array which is named ````new_y````?

Comment: I answered the "*In other words, I would like to obtain:*" question, isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: That was to explain the beginning of my question. The real question is how to get new_y and new_x more efficiently.

Comment: Another issue is that how do you create factors? As I mentioned, I will have thousands of it starting from 1 to 1000.

Comment: That's easy, but please do not ask many questions in the same post. Questions must focus on a single problem to maximize the chance that it might be useful to others once answered. Please open a new question for the factors.